# PHP: Constants best practice- 1/0 or true/false?

Tags: php

When using constants, which is best practice, if any? To set values as 1/0 or true/false?

```
define('CACHE_ENABLE', 0, true);
define('LOG_ENABLE', 1, true);
```

or

```
define('CACHE_ENABLE', false, true);
define('LOG_ENABLE', true, true);
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `1`/`0` instead of `true`/`false` in the language that supports `true`/`false` themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a ***boolean value*** which can only be true or false, use `true` and `false`.

If you have a ***numeric value*** which you want to use in math, or as a counter, or as a bitmask for several possible states beyond true/false, use an integer.

This is really the same as for all other variables, constants aren't anything special. The reason that makes sense is because it clearly signifies your ***intent***.